# How can I get rid if the peace treaty that was signed by the Empire

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have been trying to get rid of the Thalmor in Skyrim so that they don't capture me for worshiping Talos. I have traveled all over Skyrim to find the quest that gets rid of the White Gold Concordant.

Is there a quest? If so, where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In game it's not possible, the Aldmeri Dominion (AKA The Thalmor) want the Civil War in Skyrim to continue as it weakens the Empire for future plans (Skyrim still being a province of the Empire) so your best bet to undermine the Thalmor is to put an end to the Civil War by joining either the Stormclocks in Windhelm or the Imperials in Solitude and following the quest line with the side you've chosen.

While it probably doesn't matter either way, on the scale of future plot (speculation), an Imperial victory in the War would mean Skyrim is back under their control but a Stormclock Victory would mean a second enemy to the Thalmor which means a different set of tactics being used against them

Even if in game it was possible for you to blow up the embassy it may just weaken their presence in Skyrim. you'll need a full blown War since the Thalmor isn't a shadowy faction like the 6th House of the Mythic Dawn, they are a political force with armies which brought the Empire to it's knees (forcing the White-Gold Concordat) and almost wiped out the Blades.

There are a couple of Mods which expand the conflict between the Empire and the Thalmor but i don't think there is any Mod which have you go to the Summerset Isles and destroy the Thalmore completely, and even if there was it wouldn't be canon for if/when the next Elder Scrolls Publication is released (book or game, which ever)

Comment: Not quite. A Stormcloak victory would turn Skyrim into an isolationist (and more than a little racist to non-Nord) "independent province" while at the same time critically weakening the Empire, thus allowing the Aldmeri Dominion to defeat both in detail -- because when (not if) they decide to resume hostilities Skyrim isn't going to lift a finger to help the Empire... And by the time the Dominion invades Skyrim there isn't anyone *left* to lift a finger to help *them*.

Comment: @Shadur true but a Stormclock Victory will have the Dragonborn on their side and speculative wise the Dragonborn might end up like the Neraverine and be immortal with all those Dragon Souls (haven't beaten the game so not sure if the Dragonborn is still alive), considering the events of Dawnguard the Dragonborn is able to summon a dragon so that's a bit of a threat to the Thalmor. in terms of racism we can only hope it wont end up like that, i was under the impression that the Nerevarine was supposed to drive the imperials out of Morrowind, i don't think that happened

Comment: There is a dossier in the Thalmor embassy that interesting on there take of the events in Skyrim.  It has the name of a Prominent Jarl and can only be found in a main line Quest.

Comment: @mangelo yeh i saw that and it had me question which side i would support, then i asked [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59905/how-much-of-an-asset-is-ulfric-stormcloack) to help clarify things

Answer (score 3):

There is no quest to get rid of the White-Gold Concordat, I believe. See the [list of all Skyrim quests](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Quests) here. Closest thing, IMO, is to [win the civil war in favor of the Stormcloaks](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Battle_for_Solitude).

Though, gameplay-wise, the random encounters with the Thalmor will still occur. And lore-wise, the White-Gold Concordat would still be in effect in the rest of the Empire.